# /cache url requests causing 404 errors

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

We are developing a PHP webapplication. Lately our apache logs show that Apache serves a 404 error page for a particular case. The logs indicate that the HTTP_REFERER is: http://ourhost.com?gclid=some_id. The REQUEST_URI is: /cache/some_other_id.

Our webapplication is build with symfony 1.4. Our webapplication does not serve any pages beginning with /cache, it therefore serves a 404 page. The webapplication also does not serve pages containing a link to /cache/some_other_id.

Why does Google (crawler) try to visit URLs beginning with /cache?

How should we handle these 404 errors?

Comment: you are saying that some *people* see 404 with /cache urls, but also that *google crawler* is trying to visit those urls. which is it? or both?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. The application serves the 404 pages to the Google crawler. Not to users with a browser.

Comment: can you add an example access.log entry?

Comment: I do not have access yet to the full apache logs. They have to be processed by my host first. I analyzed this 404 because our application uses a custom logger which dumps the $_SERVER variable.

Comment: ok. I was interested about the user-agent doing the request, that should be visible on $_SERVER, too.

Comment: Here you go: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem it is [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059). Basically, some kind of browser extension making such requests... There is a suspicion of "Browser Companion Helper", part of "Ginyas Browser Companion" doing the requests.

I don't see much that can be done about it from the server side, except possibly advise a user that they have malware on their browser.

Comment: Yes. It seems that way. Thanks. I think I should just ignore these 404 logs?

Comment: Yes, I don't see much you can do about it, except possibly advise a user that they have malware on their browser. Please also accept if you feel this is the right answer. :)